# Where is the administration screen of script runner on jira cloud

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

In the [behaviours](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/behaviours-overview.html) overview doc of scriptrunner, it states:

> To create a new Behaviour. Go to the Administration screen, and click
>   the Behaviours link in the Behaviours section, or press gg or . and
>   type Behaviours.

I've installed scriptrunner trial version, but have no idea how to access that administration screen (the keyboard shortcut doesn't work either)

note: i'm using jira cloud
any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at Server Documentation. I believe Cloud Documentation is [here](http://scriptrunner-docs.connect.adaptavist.com/jiracloud/post-functions.html#_calculated_custom_field) and with quick look I couldn't find the section Behaviour. It might be part of their limitation for Cloud version. Take note that, Cloud plugins are using Atlassian Connect and technically it has more limitation in compare to server land.